# Axios when posting to api there isn't a response returned, but the error handling works if there is an error in the URL

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am posting to my API and where it should return a response nothing is logged to the console.

I have the following code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import axios from 'axios';

const conn = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://myurl.com',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

const Login = () => {
  const [un,setUn] = useState('');
  const [pw,setPw] = useState('');

  const pleaseLogin = (un, pw) => {

      //Hard coding the values for now
      const email = "me@mydomain.org";
      const pass = "weakpassword";

      conn.post('/apilogin/authenticate/',
        {
          email: email, password: pass
        })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("This is never reached");
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log("This is reached if I alter the URL");
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => pleaseLogin(un,pw)}>
      <label>
        User Name:
        <input type="text" value={un} onChange={setUn} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="text" value={pw} onChange={setPw} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login
```

If I change the URL then I get a 404 error so the error handling is working, but no response is logged at all if the URL is correct. If I run this call to the API through postman, then it works fine and I get a JSON response like below:

```
{
    "refresh": "tokendata",
    "access": "tokendata"
}
```

When trying using fetch, I was seeing CORS errors when logging the response, but since adding the cors setting it stopped, but I am still not seeing a response. There is no error on the server I can see, I just see 200OK when the request is processed.

This is using the Fetch method:

```
const pleaseLogin = async (un, pw) => {

  const data = { email: un, password: pw };

  fetch(`${baseUrl}/apilogin/authenticate/`, {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(response => {console.log(response)});
}
```

I have tried running react from http://localhost:3000 and from http://myipaddress:3000 as well and that hasn't made a difference.

Server logs:

```
   2020-12-03T10:04:37.365435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/apilogin/authenticate/" host=OMITTED fwd="myexternalipaddress" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=200ms status=200 bytes=761 protocol=https
2020-12-03T10:04:37.363496+00:00 app[web.1]: omitted - - [03/Dec/2020:10:04:37 +0000] "POST /apilogin/authenticate/ HTTP/1.1" 200 438 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
```

UPDATE: modified headers below.

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
},
```

UPDATE: I have tried running the react app on a development server where the API backend runs. The django application is set up to handle CORS. I have tried with Firefox and the server receives a request like below:

```
OPTIONS /api/authenticate/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

If I run the app in Chrome then it gets nothing at all. I understand that this is a pre-flight request. As far as I can tell, the server is set up to handle this. I'm not sure where to go from here. I know that other frameworks work with the same request. I have tested with static HTML as below and this works.

```
<script>


const login = async () => {

  const email = "emailaddress";
  const pass = "password";

  try {
    const response = await axios({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/authenticate/',
      method: 'post',
      data: { email: email, password: pass },
    }).then( response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

login();

</script>
```

Comment: please look for what is CORS?

Comment: check console if you are getting an error or api call in network tab.

Comment: On the network tab there are no visible errors. I have tried the same using fetch instead and I get "Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch", but no HTTP response error code. There are no visible CORS errors. I am running the API external to where the local server is running would I get CORS errors in this instance? I have only seen them when trying to run from the same host.

Comment: Is there any error in console? If your api is on another server and then your local server where you are making, that api call will give you CROS issue.
You need to set allow CROS from api server and allow CORS in api call from local server. check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I don't see any CORS errors on the server. Using Fetch, I logged the response to the console and I did see CORS errors. Then I changed it to include mode: 'cors' and those errors stopped, but still no actual response. I have added the fetch method to the post.

Answer (score 0):

try add `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"` to your `package.json` inside your `client` folder (**to overcome CORS issues**).:-

- `/client/package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "proj_name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

Then, add `async await` to your `res` (a lot of times I do stumble upon this issue & this helps me):-

- `Login.js`:-

```js
import React, {useState} from "react"
import axios from 'axios';

const conn = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://myurl.com',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

const Login = () => {
  const [un,setUn] = useState('');
  const [pw,setPw] = useState('');

  const sayHello = () => {
    console.log("hello");
  }

  const pleaseLogin = (un, pw) => {

      //Hard coding the values for now
      const email = "me@mydomain.org";
      const pass = "weakpassword";

      conn.post('/apilogin/authenticate/',
        {
          email: email, password: pass
        })
      .then(async res => {
        const result = await res
        console.log("This is never reached");
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.data);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log("This is reached if I alter the URL");
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => pleaseLogin(un,pw)}>
      <label>
        User Name:
        <input type="text" value={un} onChange={setUn} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="text" value={pw} onChange={setPw} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go later when I am back at the computer.

Comment: It hasn't worked unfortunately. Tomorrow, I will try some things with a local copy of the rest API. It seems strange that it works fine though for other apps such as ones in react-native and an older react app that I made using boiler plate code.

Comment: I have tested locally and it still doesn't work. Please see my update with the explanation. I'm going to use something else other than react as it doesn't seem to be a problem with Axios or the back end since the django-app is configured to handle cors and works with other frameworks and the request made from static html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand when you stated it works with **static HTML** in your updates above.

I seems like these part of code (show below) might have contribute to your issue:-

```js
// this part
const conn = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://myurl.com',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

```js
// and this part
conn.post('/apilogin/authenticate/',
{
  email: email, password: pass
})
.then(res => {
  console.log("This is never reached");
  console.log(res);
  console.log(res.data);
}, (error) => {
  console.log("This is reached if I alter the URL");
  console.log(error);
});
```

If you build your `axios` around that cause of wanting it to be **dynamic**. Then you could change it to your **own** **static HTML** updates (which I think can also can be dynamic with some changes):-

- `Login.js`:-

```js
import React, {useState} from "react"
import axios from 'axios';

const baseUrl = 'https://myurl.com'
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

const Login = () => {
  const [un,setUn] = useState('');
  const [pw,setPw] = useState('');

  const sayHello = () => {
    console.log("hello");
  }

  const pleaseLogin = async(un, pw) => {

      //Hard coding the values for now
      const email = "me@mydomain.org";
      const pass = "weakpassword";

      // the BASEURL & CONFIG can still be DYNAMIC
      await axios.post(baseUrl + '/apilogin/authenticate/',
        {
          email: email, password: pass
        }, config)
      .then(async res => {
        const result = await res
        console.log("This is never reached");
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("This is reached if I alter the URL");
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => pleaseLogin(un,pw)}>
      <label>
        User Name:
        <input type="text" value={un} onChange={setUn} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="text" value={pw} onChange={setPw} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login
```

Comment: Sorry, by "static HTML", "plain vanilla JavaScript" would have been a better description. I tried creating a static HTML page with the JavaScript embedded and that worked. That's not the solution, I was just testing if it worked outside of React.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the modifications in the code, but unfortunately it is still not working. On the server I see an OPTIONS request come in instead of POST. I googled this and understood that it is a pre-flight request. I looked into what needed to be done on the Django server-side and that was already done. The server appears to be able to handle the request and returns a 200 response. What it looks like to me is something is  happening at the client to stop it sending the requests properly. Chrome doesn't do anything it appears, but Firefox send the OPTIONS request.